PHP: Data not being appended to array inside closure
Closure Variable Problem Access and replace
I'm having trouble using closure variables. When I declare $data as a collection and use chunk to read a file, I want to add each chunk to my data list. However, after the process is finished, when I check the variable, it's empty (=[]). Can anyone help me? Here is my code
$data = collect();
            Excel::filter('chunk')->load($path)->chunk(100, function ($results) use (&$data) {
                foreach ($results as $row) {
                    $data = array_merge($data, [$results->toArray()]);
                }
                echo $results;
            }, true);
            dd($data);


Why use a collection? array_merge() returns a plain array, not a collection.

use $data = [] & within foreach use $data[] = $row->toArray(); .Check this.

your code triggers TypeError  array_merge(): Argument #1 must be of type array, Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection given. You should use $data = array(); or $data = []; as suggested.

why are you merging all the results for each row? This duplicates results by however many rows.

The problem with the code lies in how the $data variable is being handled within the chunk method. Initially, $data is correctly initialized as a collection, but within the chunk closure, it's being redefined as an array using array_merge(). This inconsistency causes issues because collections and arrays are not interchangeable without proper conversion.
Here's a corrected version of the code:
$data = collect();
Excel::filter('chunk')->load($path)->chunk(100, function ($results) use (&$data) {
    foreach ($results as $row) {
        $data->push($row->toArray());
    }
}, true);

dd($data);


You have two options:
$data = [];

Excel::filter('chunk')->load($path)->chunk(100, function ($results) use (&$data) {
  foreach ($results as $row) {
    $data[] = $row;
  }
}, true);

dd(collect($data)); // assuming you need $data as a collection

$data = collect([]);

Excel::filter('chunk')->load($path)->chunk(100, function ($results) use ($data) {
  foreach ($results as $row) {
    $data->push($row);
  }
}, true);

dd($data);

